# Is it possible to simplify this algorithm so that it only uses 1 loop and 2 variables?

Tags: c, algorithm, for-loop, math, mathematical-optimization

Is it possible to get the same results as this code using only a and b?
I'm trying to calculate c from a and b to avoid using a third variable, but I can't find a solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int LENGTH = 20;

int main()
{
    char arr[LENGTH];

    for (int a = 0, b = 1, c = 0; c < LENGTH; c++) {
        if (a < b) {
            arr[c] = '*';
            a++;
        } else {
            arr[c] = ' ';
            a    = 0;
            b++;
        }
    }

    printf(arr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Code result : `* ** *** **** *****`

Comment: This code has undefined behavior because it passes a non-null-terminated string to `printf()`

Comment: Add `arr[c] = 0;` just after the loop to make sure it's always NUL terminated.

Comment: That doesn't fix it for two reasons. Every character in the array is written by the loop, so there is no remaining byte in the array to put the null-terminator, furthermore, after the loop breaks, `c` is out of scope.

Comment: I'm sure you can calculate `b` based on `c` (it's kind of an reversed Pascal triangle), but the code becomes unreadable :) ... `if (a < b) ...` becomes `if (a < (complicated expression using c)) ...` or, more likely, `if (a < reversedpascal(c)) ...`

Comment: @pmg Yeah I know it's going to be less readable after that. I just wondered how to do it since I figure it was possible, but couldn't find how.

Comment: In all honesty, using two loops would be _more_ readable in my opinion. As it is now, it's essentially obfuscating the work of two loops into one loop, without any benefit to the number of iterations required. The reason to remove loops would be to reduce iterations and extra work, but this doesn't do that.

Comment: @Rogue using one loop was sadly the only requirement set by my professor.

Comment: Curse those professors and their insane requirements. Mathematically speaking, you'll need a way to calculate `c` given a specific `a` and `b` at any given moment in the loop, which can be done as a result of considering that `c = f(b) + a`, where `f(b)` would be a function of a specific `b` to an offset. This could be a summation, but there is a closed form for it.

Comment: With only (a,b), something like `for(int a=0,b=2 ; a<LENGTH ; a++) { if (a != (b*(b+1))/2-2) arr[a] = '*'; else { arr[a] = ' '; b++; } }` . That's the same idea as the answer below, but less hacky and we stay in the int universe :)  Note that the sum of numbers up to N is N(N+1)/2. You also have to fix `arr[LENGTH+1]` and add `arr[LENGTH] = 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event that checking if a number is triangular by linking or writing some sort of `sqrt()` function is not a solution that you find acceptable:

Each group of `**...` in the final string has a `' '` at the end, so the shortest segment in the string is `"* "`, which is 2 `char`s long.

The `c` in your loop is the index of the char array that this iteration should write to, the `a` is the index inside the current *group* of `'*'`s, and `b` is length of the current *group* of `'*'`s less one (since we want to count the spaces). Directly before the `if` clause in your `for` loop, it can be said that `c` is the sum from 2 to `b` plus `a`.

In other words, if `a`=0, and `b`=1, then `c`=0, because the sum from 2 to 0 is 0, plus 0 is 0.

If `a`=3, and `b`=4, then `c`= (2+3+4) + 3 = 12.

This means that you *could* write your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int LENGTH = 20;

int sumFromTwo(int in){  //Recursive function to calculate sigma(2:in)
  if(in < 2)
    return 0;
  else
    return in + sumFromTwo(in - 1);
}

int main()
{
    char arr[LENGTH + 1];  //Extra byte for null-terminator

    for (int a = 0, b = 1; sumFromTwo(b) + a < LENGTH ; ) {
        if (a < b) {
            arr[sumFromTwo(b) + a] = '*';
            a++;
        } else {
            arr[sumFromTwo(b) + a] = ' ';
            a    = 0;
            b++;
        }
    }

    arr[LENGTH] = '\0';  //Always null-terminate your strings

    printf(arr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But using recursion to avoid using a variable that is almost certainly going to be optimized into a register anyway is not going to save your computer any resources, least of all RAM, so it is definitely cleaner to do it the way you did in your question (but **please** null-terminate your string before passing it to your choice of `printf` or `puts`).

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't respect my professor's requirements about using only 1 for loop. I also like solving this by finding if the number is triangular. I forgot to mention in the post that I didn't really care about it being slower than the solution I had, I was more interested in trying to find a working algorithm with less variables.

Comment: Sorry about the null-termination, this was my first time writing in C, I'm used to Java and other higher level languages.

Comment: This is certainly not a *good* solution, but it most certainly only has only one `for` loop, and satisfies your desire to remove one of the three variables

Comment: I know it has one for loop, but we were also prohibited from other kinds of loops. Though I didn't mention it.

Comment: Recursion and loops are completely different things. No qualified programming professor would call a recursive function a breach of a 1-loop requirement unless they also explicitly forbade recursion and you didn't mention it

Comment: Why is a recursive function not a loop ?

Comment: A loop compiles into a section of machine instructions that repeats some number of times. A recursive function compiles into one function that just calls itself several times and uses extra stack frames to compute something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248208/discussion-between-willis-hershey-and-theodore-lheureux).